# Getting access-specifier error while calling virtual function of derived class which is private in base class

Tags: c++

Why I am getting access-specifier error (private-member) for the following piece of code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Derived;

class Base {
private:
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base Fun"; }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void fun() { cout << "Derived Fun"; } //this should be called
};

int main()
{
   Base *ptr = new Derived;
   ptr->fun();
   return 0;
}
```

Here, `fun()` of derived class should be called and since it is public, there should be no error.

Answer (score 6):

According to the standard (`N4140`):

> **11.5 Access to virtual functions**
>
> <sup>1</sup> The access rules (Clause 11) for a virtual function are determined by its declaration and are not affected by
>   the rules for a function that later overrides it. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> class B {
> public:
>     virtual int f();
> };
> class D : public B {
> private:
>     int f();
> };
> void f() {
>     D d;
>     B* pb = &d;
>     D* pd = &d;
>     pb->f(); // OK: B::f() is public,
>              // D::f() is invoked
>     pd->f(); // error: D::f() is private
> }
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

BTW, in general case, during compilation it is not possible to know which class is going to be called at run-time.

Consider

```
Base *ptr = GetBaseOrDerivedObject();
ptr->fun();
```

where `GetBaseOrDerivedObject`, depending on concrete run-time situation, can return a poiner to an object of type `Base` or `Derived`.

Comment: I seriously didn't get it. As per late resolution, `vptr` must be pointing to the `vtable` of derived class. Since derived class `fun()` is public, it must be called without any hassle. How does base class comes into picture here? Or I understood late binding incorrectly?

Comment: The check is done at compile time, not at run time, so it is not related to late binding.

Answer (score 0):

> Here, fun() of derived class should be called and since it is public, there should be no error.

Unfortunately, this is not true.

This works:

```
 Derived *ptr = new Derived;
 ptr->fun();
```

This doesn't work:

```
 Base *ptr = new Derived;
 ptr->fun();
```

The reason is simple: `Base` has no public member named `fun`, so you cannot access it through a pointer to `Base`.
You are allowed to set your own visibility specifier for an overridden member method in the derived class, but this does not magically promote the specifier of the base class.

---

There exists a well known idiom called *NVI* (*non virtual interface*) that is mostly based on this pattern (a private virtual member method in the base class).
You can imagine it as a refinement of the template method pattern, even though to be honest this is not true at all.